# What does the dovecot acl plugin actually do?

Tags: dovecot, imap, plugin

Can I reasonably do shared mailboxes without the acl plugin? I do personal mailbox sharing completely with unix permissions: i.e. some accounts put their mailboxes in a unix group so that everyone in that group can access it. Even the IMAP ACL RFC considers unix permission based implementations legit (i.e. some IMAP permissions end up being linked).

The sentence "When testing you could first try accessing shared/public mailboxes without ACL plugin even enabled." from the [dovecot acl doc](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/acl/) indicates that sharing works without that acl plugin.---So what does it bring to the table?

Comment: Documentation page you linked shows that the ACL module allows far more finely grained permissions than just read vs read/write

Comment: @roaima ...isn't it true that the Dovecot ACLs can only enforce _additional_ restrictions than file permissions do? And only to users who have no mail access on the file system level... Using 'finegrained' feels misleading in this context. -- The documentation totally misses to showcase the two general ways of handling mailbox sharing, how to configure them and what their pros and cons are: either a) based on file system permissions or b) combining wide open everyone-can-read-write-everything fs perms with privacy settings enforced by the acl plugin alone for IMAP(/POP?) only.

Comment: @roaima Especially if b) is not an option: the documentation makes it hard to determine and understand how to configure option a) and how such a configuration actually works.

Comment: I don't know as I don't use the ACL module in my dovecot instance. That's why it's a comment rather then an answer. I have a number of mailbox folders that are shared by two people; symlinks from one user to the other seen to work here so I never bothered to take the time to try the ACL module. If you don't think my comment is worth keeping I can remove it